# Partially hide email address in TypeScript(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using **TypeScript(Javascript)**

How can I partially hide email address like this?

- `jack.dawson@gmail.com` to `j*********n@g****.com`
- `rose.bukater@outlook.com` to `r**********r@o******.com`

I only found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545301/partially-hide-email-address-in-php) using PHP.

Thanks

Comment: You should NEVER do this through Javascript, as it is loaded client side, which means users could simply reverse it (or completely stop the script) and it would show the mail.

Comment: What is your higher level objective or problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The email address obfuscation should be done server side not in JavaScript.

Comment: @Snorlax thanks for reminding! but actually I am using angular2-meteor, so I am actually using it in the server side.

Comment: What happens if someone has an address like `mu@example.com`, `x@example.com`, `x@y.ca`, ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As stated above, this really isn't a JavaScript job, but here's something short to get you started:

```
var censorWord = function (str) {
   return str[0] + "*".repeat(str.length - 2) + str.slice(-1);
}

var censorEmail = function (email){
     var arr = email.split("@");
     return censorWord(arr[0]) + "@" + censorWord(arr[1]);
}

console.log(censorEmail("jack.dawson@gmail.com"));
```

> j*********n@g*******m

Comment: Not the same result as his though.

Comment: Close enough to get him started.

Comment: thanks @crclayton! the code helps a lot, and it is so concise!

Comment: best Javascript mask email i have got. Thank you @CharlesClayton

Answer (score 2):

Like when the lab technician makes kryptonite for Richard Prior in Superman III i've got to say "i'm not sure what you need this for, but here you go..."

Its kinda long-form but that shows the algorithm better.

```
function obscure_email(email) {
    var parts = email.split("@");
    var name = parts[0];
    var result = name.charAt(0);
    for(var i=1; i<name.length; i++) {
        result += "*";
    }
    result += name.charAt(name.length - 1);
    result += "@";
    var domain = parts[1];
    result += domain.charAt(0);
    var dot = domain.indexOf(".");
    for(var i=1; i<dot; i++) {
        result += "*";
    }
    result += domain.substring(dot);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really, really bad example. It works and should get you the idea, but man is it bad... and long. You could shorten it, but this is only to give you an idea of how it COULD be done.

https://jsfiddle.net/anoffpt9/2/

```
function changeMail(str) {
    var split = str.split("@");
    var letter1 = split[0].substring(0, 1);
    var letter2 = split[0].substring(split[0].length - 1, split[0].length);
    var newFirst = letter1;
    for(i = 0; i < split[0].length - 2; i++) {
        newFirst += "*";
    }
    newFirst += letter2;

    var letter3 = split[1].substring(0, 1);
    var extension = letter3;
    for(i = 0; i < split[1].split(".")[0].length - 1; i++) {
        extension += "*";
    }
    extension += "." + split[1].split(".")[1];
    var result = newFirst + "@" + extension;

    return result;
}
```

It's very, very bad but you should get the idea.

EDIT: Made it complete. It works well, but it's so damn long and could probably be trimmed, but there are a lot of factors that play in here (like gmail.com -> g****.com) that you need some more than just adding them.

Oh and this only accounts for mails with one extension. co.uk and subdomains will not work.. so yeah. A lot of factors that play in. It's not that easy ;)

Comment: That will definitely helps! the thing is I don't know the API `split`, but now I can make it.

Comment: @HongboMiao No problem! I've updated it with a complete answer, which works perfectly to your request :)