# How can hide the email address

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table that show some data wallet address or email.

I need when is email then hide the letters before @ like this ****@gmail.com

My table in the frontent php is:

```
<table class="table table-striped text-center"><thead><tr>
                                <th scope="col">Username</th>
                                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($withdrawHistory as $wd) {
                                echo '<tr><td>' . $wd["username"] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $wd["wallet"] . '</td>
    </tr>'; }?> </tbody></table>
```

Is there a way to hide ?

Comment: It boils down to a simple string replacement. This question about [partial hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545301/partially-hide-email-address-in-php) might give you a couple of hints.

Comment: Thank you I have already checked but I didn't find a solution. How can implament in to this code?

Comment: `echo '****'.strstr('foo@example.com', '@');`

Comment: Do you want the number of `*` to match the number of characters in the email or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table class="table table-striped text-center"><thead><tr>
                                <th scope="col">Username</th>
                                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($withdrawHistory as $wd) {
                                echo '<tr><td>' . $wd["username"] . '</td>
                                <td>' . '****'.strstr($wd["wallet"], '@') . '</td>
    </tr>'; }?> </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Thank you @dev_mustafa ! It work , but how can set to hide only the half letters ?

Comment: `substr_replace($wd["wallet"],"***",0 ,strlen(explode('@', $wd["wallet"])[0])/2)`

If the answer is useful kindly, accept it

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using explode (inside the foreach loop) and then just echo $email.

```
$wallet = explode("@", $wd["wallet"]);

$email = "****@". $wallet[1];

echo $email;
```

If you want the number of letters before @ match the number of * use this.

```
$wallet = explode("@", $wd["wallet"]);

$y = strlen($wallet[0]);

$hidden = "";

for ($x = 1; $x <= $y; $x++) {
   $hidden .= "*";
}

$email = $hidden ."@". $wallet[1];

echo $email;
```