# Regexp : catching all letters and numbers before a specific string

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to catch, in order to replace, all letters and numbers placed before a specific string in one `preg_replace`.

Example : a_dress.mail-123@aol.fr
Result : a_aaaaa.aaaa-aaa@aol.fr

I tried `(([a-z]*[^\.\-\_]*)|\d*[^\.\-\_]*)(?=(@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}))` but it only gets the last matching

[image: Matching with current regexp]

Comment: `preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9](?=[^\s@]*@)/', 'a', $text)` or `preg_replace('/[^\W_](?=[^\s@]*@)/', 'a', $text)`

Comment: Are you trying to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545301/partially-hide-email-address-in-php

Comment: @Viktor thank you ! Post it as an answer to let me validate

Comment: @NigelRen Not really because emails may not be correct emails in my case but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9](?=[^\s@]*@)/', 'a', $text)
preg_replace('/[^\W_](?=[^\s@]*@)/', 'a', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cFHI78/1).

*Details*

- `[^\W_]` / `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - a letter or digit
- `(?=[^\s@]*@)` - immediately to the right, there must be zero or more chars other than whitespaces and `@` and then a `@` char.